# How to get the support for SRT (Secure Reliable Transport) in React Native (for both iOS & Android)?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, ffmpeg, streaming

I tried many ways to get the support for SRT (Secure Reliable Transport) streaming in React Native but none of them worked. There were very few resources over the Internet and none seems to be working.
I tried using [ffmpeg library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-ffmpeg) but they are not providing the support for SRT as of now.

The following error was thrown when a valid SRT link was passed to the below code:

Code:

```
useEffect(() => {
    RNFFmpeg.execute(
      '-i "srt://<IP-ADDRESS>:<PORT>?streamid=live.sls.com/live/test2" -vcodec copy -acodec copy -strict -2 -y -f mpegts /storage/emulated/0/Download/srt_test_0.ts',
    ).then(result => console.log(`>> FFmpeg process exited with rc=${result}.`));

    return () => {
      console.log('cancelling all executions');
      RNFFmpeg.cancel();
    };
  }, []);
```

Output:

```
srt://<IP-ADDRESS>:<PORT>?streamid=live.sls.com/live/test2: Protocol not found
index.js:115 Did you mean file:srt://<IP-ADDRESS>:<PORT>?streamid=live.sls.com/live/test2index.js:22 
>> FFmpeg process exited with rc=1.
```

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Did you get any solution for this?

Comment: Not yet. We had changed our strategies for what we wanted. I'm not following this thread since then. @Yuyutsu